# How to convert text in a column to a different format based on a custom dictionary?

Tags: python, r, nlp, text-mining, corpus

I’m looking to make the education data in my dataset consistent based on a dictionary of university/college names. How do I run code against my dictionary and get the output I want? The data consists of abbreviations and colloquial names.

Can someone provide an example of this in R. I’m willing to try it in python also, R is just my preference.

This is an example of my dictionary:

```
*University Name Dictionary
California Institute of Technology
New York University
Massachusetts Institute of Technology
Georgia Institute of Technology
Rutgers University
University of California, Berkley
University of California, Los Angeles
```

This is my data:

```
*Education
Cal Tech
NYU
MIT
Ga Tech
Georgia Tech
Rutgers
Berkley
UCLA
```

This is what I want:

```
*Education      *New Education
Cal Tech        California Institute of Technology
NYU             New York University
MIT             Massachusetts Institute of Technology
Ga Tech         Georgia Institute of Technology
Georgia Tech    Georgia Institute of Technology
Rutgers         Rutgers University
Berkley         University of California, Berkley
UCLA            University of California, Los Angeles
```

Apologies if there is already a solution for this, I just could not find it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: So you want to get `New York University` from `NYU` or vice-versa ?

Comment: `pandas` has `.replace(dictionary)` and you use dictionary like `{"Cal Tech": "California Institute of Technology"}`

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` has function `replace(dictionary)` where `dictionary` is like

```
 {"Cal Tech": "California Institute of Technology"}
```

Because `pandas.DataFrame` is inspired by `R` so probably `R` has something similar.

---

```
data = {
    'Cal Tech': 'California Institute of Technology',
    'NYU': 'New York University',
    'MIT': 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology',
    'Ga Tech': 'Georgia Institute of Technology',
    'Georgia Tech': 'Georgia Institute of Technology',
    'Rutgers': 'Rutgers University',
    'Berkley': 'University of California, Berkley',
    'UCLA': 'University of California, Los Angeles',
}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Education': ['Cal Tech', 'NYU', 'MIT', 'Ga Tech', 'Georgia Tech', 'Rutgers', 'Berkley', 'UCLA']
})

df['New Education'] = df['Education'].replace(data)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Education                          New Education
0      Cal Tech     California Institute of Technology
1           NYU                    New York University
2           MIT  Massachusetts Institute of Technology
3       Ga Tech        Georgia Institute of Technology
4  Georgia Tech        Georgia Institute of Technology
5       Rutgers                     Rutgers University
6       Berkley      University of California, Berkley
7          UCLA  University of California, Los Angeles
```

---

If you use `regex=True` then it can replace also in longer string

```
data = {
    'Cal Tech': 'California Institute of Technology',
    'NYU': 'New York University',
    'MIT': 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology',
    'Ga Tech': 'Georgia Institute of Technology',
    'Georgia Tech': 'Georgia Institute of Technology',
    'Rutgers': 'Rutgers University',
    'Berkley': 'University of California, Berkley',
    'UCLA': 'University of California, Los Angeles',
}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Education': ['I am from MIT']
})

df['New Education'] = df['Education'].replace(data, regex=True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
       Education                                    New Education
0  I am from MIT  I am from Massachusetts Institute of Technology
```

---

Doc: [pandas.DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to do this without hard-coding it? The data set is very large and will get more colleges added to it that may be in different formats. It would not be reasonable for us to hard card every possible form of the college name...

Comment: it is only example which everyone can run without extra data. But in real code you can do whatever you want to create dictionary. You can read from file, you can read from database, you can scrape from webpage, you can convert data from DataFrame, etc.